# How to use individual materialize css components

Tags: javascript, webpack, materialize

I've installed materialize-css using `npm`.
https://materializecss.com/
How can I import individual components (like button, navbar) instead of the full build?
I'm using webpack as well.
I see files such as `buttons.js`, but I can't import them. Also obviously I want to set up minification for the components that I use.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to get whatever component you want to include is to setup your build using SASS/SCSS. That way choosing which component you want is as simple as including an @import statement like:

```
@import "components/buttons";
@import "components/grid";
@import "components/datepicker";
```

But if you dont want to learn SCSS syntax, try this: http://materialize.khophi.co

Comment: But that will only apply to the CSS isn't it? I thought it would be possible to `import` single components like it is done with webpack.

Comment: I see what you mean...I haven't separated the JS before but it looks like there is a discussion about it here: https://github.com/Dogfalo/materialize/issues/5958